# Not able to see Windows 7 computer sharing folders within LAN

Tags: windows-7, lan

I don't see the Windows 7 computer at all in the list. I am able to see shared files of the Ubuntu 14.04 computer from the Windows 7, but not the other way around.

I tried to use other clients like FileZilla, PuTTY ssh with the same result.

This is what I got when I ran the command `sudo mount -t ntfs \\216.47.154.95\Ks\ /mnt/windows -o username=MMAE` after creating the directory `/mnt/windows` and mounting my Windows drive.

```
:~$ sudo mount -t ntfs \\216.47.154.95\Ks\ /mnt/windows -o username=MMAE 
Usage: mount -V                 : print version
       mount -h                 : print this help
       mount                    : list mounted filesystems
       mount -l                 : idem, including volume labels
So far the informational part. Next the mounting.
The command is `mount [-t fstype] something somewhere'.
Details found in /etc/fstab may be omitted.
       mount -a [-t|-O] ...     : mount all stuff from /etc/fstab
       mount device             : mount device at the known place
       mount directory          : mount known device here
       mount -t type dev dir    : ordinary mount command
Note that one does not really mount a device, one mounts
a filesystem (of the given type) found on the device.
One can also mount an already visible directory tree elsewhere:
       mount --bind olddir newdir
or move a subtree:
       mount --move olddir newdir
One can change the type of mount containing the directory dir:
       mount --make-shared dir
       mount --make-slave dir
       mount --make-private dir
       mount --make-unbindable dir
One can change the type of all the mounts in a mount subtree
containing the directory dir:
       mount --make-rshared dir
       mount --make-rslave dir
       mount --make-rprivate dir
       mount --make-runbindable dir
A device can be given by name, say /dev/hda1 or /dev/cdrom,
or by label, using  -L label  or by uuid, using  -U uuid .
Other options: [-nfFrsvw] [-o options] [-p passwdfd].
For many more details, say  man 8 mount.
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the Network and Sharing Center window, click on “**Change advanced sharing settings**.”

[image]

For your current profile, adjust the following two settings:

- Turn on network discovery
- Turn on file and printer sharing

[image]

Click on “Save Changes” after those settings are configured. Now Check whether you can able to see the file of ubuntu

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I had checked this. They both are on for guest or public. I switched off firewall too. Still not working.

Comment: Also, I checked both computers are in same workgroup.

Comment: Could you plz be more specific...you wish to see window files on ubuntu or vice versa.

Comment: Yes. I want to see windows computer files on Ubuntu computer. I have access to the ubuntu computer all the time but not the windows computer. Currently, I am able to see the ubuntu computer files from the windows computer but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have mounted the shared drive in ubuntu and you can list the drive with the following command

```
root@ubuntu-desktop:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        71G   47G   21G  70% /
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           784M  812K  783M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  144K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
cgroup          2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

If not create a mount point(**/mnt/windows**) in your machine and mount your windows drive

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/windows

sudo mount –t ntfs \\servername\sharename /mountpoint –o username=userid
```

It will ask you for the windows administrator password and you can enter it

**eg:**

```
sudo mount –t ntfs \\192.168.1.150\vmsdata\ /mnt/windows –o username=henry
```

Now Edit your **fstab** file and check whether you have the entry for your windows share.

```
vi /etc/fstab
```

If no entry, add the entry to your fstab file and check whether you can able to view the files.

Once you mounted your windows drive confirm the same by viewing the drives with the command

```
df -h
```

**Note:** Please confirm whether you can able to ping your windows machine from Ubuntu machine

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I could not mount it. I have attached the output at the end of this post as an answer (because it was too long to fit as a comment).

Comment: If still u unable to mount the drive, add the drive entry in fstab file and use the command (sudo mount -a ) to mount the drive. Please refer the link http://www.7tutorials.com/accessing-shared-partitions-ubuntu-windows-7

Comment: Hi Vembu. This worked. Thank you very much for the help. This is going to save me a lot of walking between experiment room and my office.

Comment: That sounds good :)